# How to find articulation points in a graph using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I'm trying to write a Postgres function that returns the results of every articulation point in an undirected graph. But I can't figure out how to do this properly in relation to relational programming. So for example, if the graph is

```
select * from graph;
source | target
--------+--------
  1 |      2
  2 |      1
  1 |      3
  3 |      1
  2 |      3
  3 |      2
  2 |      4
  4 |      2
  2 |      5
  5 |      2
  4 |      5
  5 |      4
(12 rows)
```

then the result should be

```
select articulation_point();
articulation_point
--------------------
         2
(1 row)
```

But I have no idea how to go about this. I've read some articles on how to do this in a programming language like Python, but no idea how to approach it in Postgres.

Comment: nobody is gonna do your homework, rewrite the function in `PL/pgSQL`, post if you have a problem. Or instal `plpython` and write a function in python

Comment: I'm not asking for the answer, just a lending hand or a nod towards the right direction. Thanks for the advice though. I'll look into the first idea since I don't think plpython is permitted.

Comment: Wow. We are in the same class - B561 right? Don't worry though. I'm struggling with this too. However, posting on Stack? come on now.